# Keyboard Modifiers not being used

Tags: shortcut

I'm curious, is there a way to use those modifier keys shown in the image, it seems that Blender doesn't recognize the  <kbd>Win</kbd> key also, and all the modifiers ( <kbd>Right</kbd> and  <kbd>Left</kbd>) are the same.

I'm open to any external tricks that maybe you can work on the keymap file or any thing really.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The <kbd>Win</kbd> key is equivalent to the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> key on Apple devices and is intercepted by the operating system. In a [Blender event](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Event.html) these are both treated as <kbd>OS Key</kbd>  You can, in theory, set a Blender keymap entry using it, but odds are that the OS will have already assigned the key and won't pass it along.

There are entries in the keymap that use <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> but in every case, both are mapped to the same operation and there's no documentation on how to separate them.  However, they do appear distinct in Blender events.

So the upshot is that in theory this can be done, but in practice it doesn't seem possible, unless you write Python code that has a keyboard event handler.